# Getting Internal Error 500 in Laravel Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to create an add form so that the page will not be refreshed when they clicked submit. AJAX seems the tool for this. However, I'm getting Internal Error 500 when I click the submit button. Here is the code:

***service-type.blade.php***

```
{!!Form::open(['id' => 'frm-add'])!!}

    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#iconModal').modal('show');
            });
        </script>
    @endif

    <div ng-controller="serviceTypeController">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-3 label-control" for="eventRegInput1">*Names</label>
            <!-- <label>[[service.typename]]</label> -->
            <div class="col-md-9">
                {!! Form::text('typeName', null, ['id' => 'name', 
                                                    'class' => 'form-control', 
                                                    'ng-model' => 'service.typename', 
                                                    'placeholder' => 'eg.Health', 
                                                    'maxlength' => '20', 'required', 
                                                    'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 
                                                    'data-trigger' => 'focus', 
                                                    'data-placement' => 'top', 
                                                    'data-title' => 'Maximum of 20 characters', 
                                                    'minlength' => '5', 
                                                    'pattern' => '^[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$']) !!}
            </div>  

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-3 label-control" for="eventRegInput1">Description</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                {!! Form::textarea('desc', null, ['id'=>'desc', 
                                                    'class' => 'form-control', 
                                                    'ng-model' => 'service.desc', 
                                                    'maxlength' => '500',
                                                    'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                                                    'data-trigger' => 'focus',
                                                    'data-placement' => 'top',
                                                    'data-title' => 'Maximum of 500 characters']) !!}
            </div>  

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row last">
            <label class="col-md-3 label-control">*Status</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="input-group col-md-9">
                    <label class="inline custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" id="actstat" value="active" name="stat" checked="" class="custom-control-input" ng-model="service.status">
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        <span class="custom-control-description ml-0">Active</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="inline custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" id="actstat" value="inactive" name="stat"  class="custom-control-input" ng-model="service.status">
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        <span class="custom-control-description ml-0">Inactive</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
            }
        });

        $('#frm-add').submit(function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/service-type/store') }}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {typeName: $("#name").val(), 
                        typeDesc: $("#desc").val(), 
                        archive: $("input[id=actstat]:checked").val(),
                        status: 1}, 
                success: function ( _response ){
                    swal("Successful", 
                            "Service type has been added!", 
                            "success");
                    console.log("Success");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }, 
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = xhr.responseText;
                    swal("ERROR", 
                            "Error has been caughts:\n" + err.Message, 
                            "error");
                    console.log("Error found: " + error);
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .done(function( _data ) {
                console.log(data);
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" name="btnAdd">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning mr-1">Cancel</button>

     {!! Form::close() !!}
```

***ServiceTypeController.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \App\Models\Servicetype;
use \Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class ServiceTypeController extends Controller
{
   public function index() {
        $serviceTypes = ServiceType::select('typeID', 'typeName', 'typeDesc', 'status')
                                                    -> where([
                                                                ['archive', '=', 0]
                                                                ])
                                                    -> get();

        return view('service-type') -> with('serviceTypes', $serviceTypes);
    }

    public function store(Request $r) {
        try{
            $this->validate($r, [
                'typeName' => 'required|unique:servicetypes|max:20',
                ]);

            if($_POST['stat']=="active")
            {
                $stat = 1;
            }
            else if($_POST['stat']=="inactive")
            {
                $stat = 0;
            }

            $aah = ServiceType::insert(['typeName'=>trim($r->typeName),
                                                'archive'=>0,
                                                'typeDesc'=>$r->desc,
                                                'status'=>$stat]);
        } catch (Exception $exp) {
            // echo "<script>console.log('Exception Caught!\\n' + " . $exp . ");</script>";
        }


        return back();
    }

    public function getEdit(Request $r) {

        if($r->ajax())
        {
            return response(ServiceType::find($r->typeID));
        }


    }

    public function edit(Request $r)
    {

        $type = ServiceType::find($r->input('type_ID'));
        $type->typeName = $r->input('typeName');
        $type->typeDesc = $r->input('type_desc');
        $type->status = $r->input('stat');
        $type->save();
        return redirect('service-type');
    }

    public function delete(Request $r)
    {

        $type = ServiceType::find($r->input('typeID'));
        $type->archive = true;
        $type->save();
        return redirect('service-type');
    }
}
```

***web.php***

```
Route::get('/service-type/getEdit', 'FacilityTypeController@getEdit');
Route::post('/service-type/store', 'FacilityTypeController@store');
Route::post('/service-type/update','FacilityTypeController@edit');
Route::post('/service-type/delete','FacilityTypeController@delete');
Route::resource('/service-type', 'ServiceTypeController');
```

I also added `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to the master blade template.

I tried changing `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()` to `'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')`. I also tried changing `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to `<meta name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`. I tried adding `{{ csrf_field() }}` to the form. I tried echoing the exception in try catch inside controller. I tried renaming the ID of the two radio buttons to `stat` and changing `status: $("input[id=actstat]:checked").val()},` to `status: $("input[name=stat]:checked").val()},` None of them worked. The catch block didn't echo (or showed alert). The error `swal()` and `console.log()` always shows when I clicked submit. I tried adding `return false` but again, it didn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: If you check your [Network] tab in your [Google chrome console], Did you see your [/service-type] url when you submit the [form]?

Comment: Yes there is an entry 'service-type' in Network tab

Comment: Check that url and see if theres a given message there either on [Response] or [Preview]

Comment: How would I see the given message? All I can see here is the columns `name`, `status`, `type`, `initiator`, `size`, `time`, `waterfall`, as well as the meter on how long the dependency loads. BTW, I tried adding `'_token': token,` in ajax data then pass it to Laravel Controller. It saves the data to the database BUT it hangs for about 15 to 30 seconds and finally reloads the whole page. It will not show any alerts or `console.log()` but will just reload the page with the new inserted data.

Comment: @BryanJames You will need to click on it.

Comment: Oh is that so, I'm sorry for that. The Network tab in my chrome seems to list down the resources that has been loaded on the page. When I click `service-type` and navigate to the response and preview tabs, it seems that both of them has the same content. It contains an html of what looked like the `service-type.blade.php`. It's almost the same as the `elements` tab

Comment: On your [ajax], Try to add this property (dataType : 'json'). Refresh then make your way to debug the problem in your controller